# Java jasper reports valueAxis position

Tags: java, charts, jasper-reports, position

I would like to change the valueAxis(bar) to be on the right side of my stacked bar. Am struggling to change it cause once i change the position then i will change the orientation.

Please find below my source

```
<barPlot>
<plot orientation="Horizontal">
  <seriesColor seriesOrder="0" color="#FFFF80"/>
  <seriesColor seriesOrder="1" color="#FF8000"/>
  <seriesColor seriesOrder="2" color="#F47A00"/>
</plot>
<itemLabel/>
  <categoryAxisFormat>
<axisFormat/>
</categoryAxisFormat>
<valueAxisFormat>
<axisFormat/>
</valueAxisFormat>
</barPlot>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a chart customizer to your chart to make the modification.
Learn about how to do that here: http://mdahlman.wordpress.com/2010/08/18/chart-customizers-1/

The command you need to change the axis location is [setRangeAxisLocation](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/plot/CategoryPlot.html#setRangeAxisLocation%28org.jfree.chart.axis.AxisLocation%29).

```
plot.setRangeAxisLocation(AxisLocation.BOTTOM_OR_RIGHT);
```

So your customizer would look something like this:

```
public class myCustomizer implements JRChartCustomizer {
  public void customize(JFreeChart chart, JRChart jasperChart) {
    CategoryPlot plot = (CategoryPlot) chart.getPlot();
    plot.setRangeAxisLocation(AxisLocation.BOTTOM_OR_RIGHT);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response is this correct chart customizer? `net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRChartCustomizer` because am working with a stacked bar chart.When I add the script do I add in the source in the barplot tag? Am afraid am struggling to get through using the links